# How to split all the variables from a dataframe?

Tags: r, split

I have a table like:

```
$V1      $V2        $V3
toto|380 peper|728A tomato|I765
toto|458 peper|798A ognion|L965
toto|3L0 ginger|2R8A lemon|I765
```

And I would like to split it  by the "|" and finally get :

```
$V1  $V2   $V3
toto peper tomato
toto peper ognion
toto ginger lemon
```

I tried with:

```
split(data, sep="|")
```

but it's not working.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you share the output of `dput(data)`. It's not exactly clear what your input data structure is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely looking for `sub` or `gsub`, or possibly `strsplit`--but definitely not `split`:

```
mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, function(x) {
    sub("\\|.*$", "", x)
})
mydf
##   X.V1   X.V2   X.V3
## 1 toto  peper tomato
## 2 toto  peper ognion
## 3 toto ginger  lemon
```